# Is it possible have specific versions of an app depending on the operating system's version?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I read many links about the possibility to download previously version of a app in the App Store but I'm really confused.

I have to release a new version of app that it's now developed in Swift (so I have to release it from 7.0). The problem is... the customer. He asked me to leaving the possibility to download the app to previous operating systems (iOS 6.0) not only for the customer that already purchased it but also for new users that have iOS 6.0

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for the previous customers but not really for new customers.  The only way for a new customer to do it is to add the app to their itunes account from their mac.  This would make it so that they are technically a current customer when they go to download the app from their phone.  Other than that, most people that actually use their iPhone to download apps are on iOS7+.  I would not be worried about missing out on some huge market by not supporting iOS 6.